# questions about matrix

Tags: matrices

I want to create a simple matrix and the code is given below, but I got error when I compile it. Could anyone help with this?

```
$$e^{-{\cal L}=
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\    
\end{array}  
\right]$$
```

Comment: you are missing a right brace in `e^{-{\cal L}`

Comment: If you use a `bmatrix` you won't have to specify the delimiters and the centering. And you can use `\cdots` instead of multiple columns. Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: The problem with forgetting braces would be easier to solve if `\mathcal{L}` is used instead of `{\cal L}` which has been obsolete for twenty years.

Comment: Your equation is mathematically impossible because this matrix has determinant zero, and `e^{-L}` has matrix inverse `e^{+L}` (or `\det e^{-L}=\exp(-trace of L)\neq 0`).

Answer (score 9):

Or you might need something like below.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in  your production
\[
e^{-\mathcal{L} }
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\[-1ex]
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please change it into `e^{-\mathcal{L}}`?

Comment: you might also want to insert a small negative vertical space just before the line with all the dots so that the gaps are symmetcical.  `\\[-.5ex]` might do it.  don't leave a space after the `\\ ` -- `amsmath` cleverly notices a space there and assumes the bracket does *not* mean a spacing adjustment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: `\\[-1ex]` rather than `\\[-.5ex]` will do better but it is still not the exactest value I think.

Comment: I wonder if the OP in fact wanted `1`'s on the diagonal, because as it stands this matrix equation has no solution in `L`.